# Why the circle path of the cashapelayer is not so round?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer

The doucumet said that the CAShapLayer is anti-aliased ,why got this result.
I also draw a circle with the CGContext in the drawRect method,It's very perfect.

```
   UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(150, 300, 136, 136)]];

    self.circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    self.circleLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    self.circleLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    self.circleLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6].CGColor;
    [self.layer addSublayer:self.circleLayer];
```

[image]

Comment: Are you asking us how to turn off anti-aliasing? Or is your Core Graphics rendition also doing anti-aliasing, and you're just wondering why the two differ a little?

Comment: BTW, I find that if you use `UIBezierPath` method `addArcWithCenter` with non-integer radius (e.g 150.2 vs 150), the artifacts of `CAShapeLayer`'s anti-aliasing is less distracting.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the UIBezierPath docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithOvalInRect%3a), `bezierPathWithOvalInRect:` "creates a closed subpath that **approximates** the oval using a sequence of Bézier curves," so it may not draw a perfect circle.

Comment: But [CGContextAddEllipseInRect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextAddEllipseInRect) also said :" The ellipse is approximated by a sequence of Bézier curves."

Comment: When I use CGContextAddEllipseInRect draw a circle in the drawRect ,It's a perfect circle.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a UIBezierPath to draw a circle will not a perfect circle because its an approximation from Bézier curves.

You can draw a perfect circle from a square UIView. For example:

> `myView.layer.cornerRadius = myView.frame.size.width/2;`

In this topic explain three methods to draw a circle -> [How to draw a smooth circle with CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316705/how-to-draw-a-smooth-circle-with-cashapelayer-and-uibezierpath)

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 12**:
I had the same issue on iPhone XS and XS Max. I don't know why, but on iPhone 8 there was no issue. The circle was perfectly round.

To solve the issue on XS and XS Max I set the `flatness` property of `UIBezierPath` to 0.0 and made sure that the center of the rect used for `UIBezierPath` is either an integer number or a floating number of e.g. 25.5. The center of my rect was y=51.166666 and this caused the issue that the oval was not round.