# Draw circle using CAShapelayer issue

Tags: ios, swift, draw, geometry, uibezierpath

I'm drawing many circles using UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer the issue is the edge of the circles are not rendered properly and it looks like a saw like in the screenshot below :

[image]

I tried to fix the problem by forcing the performance with this snippet but did not work:

```
   shapeLayer.shouldRasterize = true
   shapeLayer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Comment: Its not a swift issue. Its an issue wth how CAShapelayer draws circle. Try increasing rasterizationScale shapeLayer.rasterizationScale = 2*UIScreen.main.scale. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316705/how-to-draw-a-smooth-circle-with-cashapelayer-and-uibezierpath) question.

Comment: thanks @PuneetSharma it is much better now by increasing rasterizationScale.

Comment: @Ayoup Nouri: Also, if you are not animating these layers, you can simply use square UIViews with corner radius equal to size/2. That would be very smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @PunetSharma in fact i had only to increase the scale for retina devices as explained in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316705/how-to-draw-a-smooth-circle-with-cashapelayer-and-uibezierpath) to be:

```
shapeLayer.rasterizationScale = 2.0 * UIScreen.main.scale
```